# When untied inputs are necessary, what is the technology to use for an OR gate?

Tags: digital-logic

What is the best technology to implement for an OR gate when there will be an open input?  I would prefer a common IC.

[image]

I wired a quadruple 2 input positive OR gate, HD74LS32P.  I have a PWM signal coming in the 1A input.  The 1B input will have another PWM signal coming in when it is powered on.  But there may be the case when it is not powered on.  Unfortunately for me, when powered off, the signal line 1B becomes high and thus the output 1Y is high.  I need 1B to be low when the 1B device is powered off.

I read on this site that I should tie the unused pins to something, and can implement that.

Comment: When you need 1B low, then pull it down....?

Comment: Does input 1B float high or does it actively assume logic 1 when disabled?

Comment: 1B floats high with nothing.

Comment: I added a 10K resistor for a pull-down to ground and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tie the input to ground, directly or through a jumper (jumper is useful if you want to change something later). Tying an input of an 'OR' gate to logic '1' would not make much sense since the output would always be high, but if you want to do that, it's good practice to use a series resistor of about 1K with LSTTL (practice from TTL days).

If you are using LSTTL or TTL, leaving an input open will result in a logic '1' but it can also pick up noise.

If you use HC or other CMOS logic families you should **always** tie **all** unused inputs either high or low, on all gates (even unused ones- this is good practice with TTL/LSTTL but essential with CMOS).

Comment: This answered worked. A pull-down resistor of 10K was used.